# Raspberry PI controllable Christmas Tree

Tags: python, python-2.x, flask, raspberry-pi

After having the scales, thermometer and a coffeemaker connected to the internet, it is finally time for Christmas Tree to become smarter.

#### Hardware

- 6ft Christmas Tree
- [An addressable WS2811 LED strip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075T84ZR3) (3x50 was good enough for this tree size)
- [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.adafruit.com/element14-raspberry-pi-zero)
- [Voltage level shifter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014MC1OAG) (3.3V to 5V)
- [Power Supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M0KLECZ)

#### Software

- used [rpi_ws281x](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x) Python samples as a base library for controlling the LEDs
- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app served at a specific port which is forwarded to the internet (to control via IFTTT)
- [`webcolors`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3) library to map between color names and RGB values

---

Currently, I've only implemented a few actions/patterns:

- wipe with a specific color (given as a color name)
- "rainbow" pattern
- "crazy" pattern (also called "theater chase" in the `rpi_ws281x` samples)
- "stop" - turn off - all LEDs black

#### The Code

**Flask part**

```
from flask import Flask

from libs import LEDStrip


app = Flask(__name__)
led_strip = LEDStrip(count=150)


@app.route('/wipe/<color>')
def wipe_color(color):
    led_strip.color_wipe(color)

    return "Wipe with {color} - success!".format(color=color)


@app.route('/rainbow')
def rainbow():
    led_strip.rainbow()
    led_strip.rainbow_cycle()

    return "Rainbow animation executed successfully!"


@app.route('/crazy')
def crazy():
    led_strip.theater_chase_rainbow()

    return "Crazy christmas tree animation executed successfully!"


@app.route('/stop')
def stop():
    led_strip.clear()

    return "Christmas tree was turned off!"
```

**libs.py**

```
import time

from webcolors import name_to_rgb
from neopixel import *

from exceptions import ColorNotFoundException


def wheel(pos):
    """Generate rainbow colors across 0-255 positions."""
    if pos < 85:
        return Color(pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3, 0)
    elif pos < 170:
        pos -= 85
        return Color(255 - pos * 3, 0, pos * 3)
    else:
        pos -= 170
        return Color(0, pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3)


class LEDStrip:
    def __init__(self,  count,
                 pin=18, frequency=800000,
                 dma=5, brightness=255,
                 invert=False, channel=0,
                 strip_type=ws.WS2811_STRIP_RGB):
        """
        LED strip abstraction class.

        :param count: number of LED pixels
        :param pin: GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!)
        :param frequency: LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
        :param dma: DMA channel to use for generating signal
        :param brightness: set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
        :param invert: True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
        :param channel: set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53
        :param strip_type: strip type and colour ordering
        """

        self.led_count = count
        self.strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(count, pin, frequency, dma, invert, brightness, channel, strip_type)
        self.strip.begin()

    def clear(self):
        self.color_wipe("black")

    def color_wipe(self, color, wait_ms=30):
        """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
        try:
            color_value = Color(*name_to_rgb(color))
        except ValueError:
            raise ColorNotFoundException("Color {color} not found.".format(color=color))

        for led_number in range(self.led_count):
            self.strip.setPixelColor(led_number, color_value)
            self.strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

    def theater_chase(self, color, wait_ms=50, iterations=10):
        """Movie theater light style chaser animation."""
        for j in range(iterations):
            for q in range(3):
                for i in range(0, self.led_count, 3):
                    self.strip.setPixelColor(i + q, color)

                self.strip.show()
                time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

                for led_number in range(0, self.led_count, 3):
                    self.strip.setPixelColor(led_number + q, 0)

    def rainbow(self, wait_ms=20, iterations=1):
        """Draw rainbow that fades across all pixels at once."""
        for j in range(256 * iterations):
            for led_number in range(self.led_count):
                self.strip.setPixelColor(led_number, wheel((led_number + j) & 255))

            self.strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

    def rainbow_cycle(self, wait_ms=20, iterations=5):
        """Draw rainbow that uniformly distributes itself across all pixels."""
        for j in range(256 * iterations):
            for led_number in range(self.led_count):
                self.strip.setPixelColor(led_number, wheel((int(led_number * 256 / self.led_count) + j) & 255))

            self.strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

    def theater_chase_rainbow(self, wait_ms=50):
        """Rainbow movie theater light style chaser animation."""
        for j in range(256):
            for q in range(3):
                for led_number in range(0, self.led_count, 3):
                    self.strip.setPixelColor(led_number + q, wheel((led_number + j) % 255))

                self.strip.show()
                time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

                for led_number in range(0, self.led_count, 3):
                    self.strip.setPixelColor(led_number + q, 0)
```

**exceptions.py**

```
class ChristmasError(BaseException):
    pass


class ColorNotFoundException(ChristmasError):
    pass
```

Aside from Google Home & Alexa voice control abilities like "Okay Google - Turn the Christmas Tree green" and "Okay Google - Make a rainbow", it is a lot of fun connecting that with motion sensors and other smart devices.

What do you think about the overall design of the `LEDStrip` class and the flask app? What do you think I can improve? I would also appreciate any ideas about the ways I can continue making it more fun this Christmas.

Note that there is already a plenty of things to address [security-wise](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/176022/58553).

Comment: I'm wondering why your `ColourNotFoundException` needs to call `Christmas Error`. Can it not be just set up as `class ColourNotFoundException(BaseException): pass`. P.S Sorry if the question is stupid, I didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: Or could you do `ColourNotFoundException = Exception("")`

Comment: @13ros27 I've just a got a habit of defining custom exceptions this way, to ease debugging and to provide better readability in error-handling and modularity. In my case, it's just one custom exception except the base one but I expect (pun intended) the module to grow and accounted for that..thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- I would suggest to separate the concerns of coloring and animating. Now, in particular `theater_chase_rainbow` duplicates code from other methods. Instead, have `theater_chase` take a color array as parameter. If you then add some animation styles and color schemes you can have \$O(n^2)\$ amount of fun trying all combinations.
- It seems to me that in this code `i + q` can overflow `led_count` if it is not a multiple of 3:

  ```
  for i in range(0, self.led_count, 3):
      self.strip.setPixelColor(i + q, color)
  ```

  Instead, I would use

  ```
  for i in range(q, self.led_count, 3):
      self.strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
  ```